# ASP.NET 4.5 Bundling in Debug Mode - Stale Resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

Is there any way we can make the ASP.NET 4.5 Bundling functionality generate GUID's as part of the querystring when running in **debug** mode (e.g bundling turned OFF).

The problem is when developing locally, the scripts/CSS files are generated like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/myscript.js" />
```

So if i change that file, i need to do a hard-refresh (sometimes a few times) to get the file to be picked up by the browser - annoying.

Is there any way we can make it render out like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/myscript.js?v=x" />
```

Where `x` is a GUID (e.g always unique).

Ideas?

I'm on ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the NuGet package is patched as per the other answer above, for now i've ended up using the same wrapper code i did for the beta NuGet package:

```
private static IHtmlString JsUnbundled(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string bundlePath)
{
    var jsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var file in BundleResolver.Current.GetBundleContents(bundlePath))
    {
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("script");
        tagBuilder.Attributes["src"] = file.AddCacheKey(); // add GUID
        tagBuilder.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
        jsBuilder.AppendLine(tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(jsBuilder.ToString());
}
```

I then have another HTML helper which checks if debug, then uses the above - otherwises uses `Scripts.Render`.

Obviously this doesn't do any kind of hashing of the file - it will ALWAYS request the file. But i don't mind this, as it's only for debug.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently examine the contents of the files in debug mode, but we could add this feature.

I filed it as an issue on codeplex [here](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/40).

Comment: Okay thanks. Guess for now ill wrap an IF DEBUG conditional around rendering out the file, then add a cache key.

Comment: Was this feature ever implemented? If so how do you turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

Try HashCache: https://github.com/kemmis/System.Web.Optimization.HashCache

Execute the ApplyHashCache() extension method on the BundlesCollection Instance after all bundles have been added to the collection.

```
BundleTable.Bundles.ApplyHashCache();
```

This will add content hashes to the script/style tags output when in debug mode.